# Converting a div with attribute "hidden" to pdf with jsPDF and html2canvas

Tags: javascript, jspdf, html2canvas

I'm using **jsPDF** and **html2canvas** to convert a `div` to **pdf**:

```
<a onclick="makePdf()">PDF</a>
<div id="divToPdf">Some content here</div>
```

However I don't want my `div` displayed on the screen. I tried using `hidden` property to hide the `div`:

```
<a onclick="makePdf()">PDF</a>
<div id="divToPdf" hidden>Some content here</div>
```

The problem is that the `hidden` property results in a **blank pdf** document. How do I go about hiding the `div` without this problem?

Answer (score 6):

To hide an HTML tag; add this attribute tag `data-html2canvas-ignore="true"` instead of the `hidden`.

Answer (score 4):

So with **Mario Alexandro Santini's** suggestion in the comments, I was able to solve the problem. I used **jquery** to *unhide* the `div` in my `makePdf()` function then *hide* it again after **jsPDF** and **html2canvas** had done their "magic":

```
function makePdf() {
    $("#divToPdf").attr("hidden", false);
    ...
    $("#divToPdf").attr("hidden", true);
}
```

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0):

You could change the layout of your page on different media through css.

This is true for printing too.

So you could write a dedicated stylesheet that is valid only when you print the page in pdf.

Please have a look at:

```
@media print {
   ...
}
```

For your example you could use a code like:

```
@media print {
   div[hidden] {
      display: block;
   }
   ...
}
```

This should select the div with `hidden` attribute and made those visible.

If you prefere the programatic approach then you could get all div in the page with attribute `hidden` and remove the attribute, print your document, than put the attribute back.

You could use something like:

```
var hideDivs = document.querySelectorAll("div[hidden]");
```

Comment: I tried both. None worked. I'm actually converting the `div` to pdf, not printing it.The media query in your answer seems to be for printing.

Comment: I don't know how your `makePdf()` works, if you use some kind of lib to directly convert the page content to pdf, then you have to use the second way: changing the page with the `querySelectorAll` before call the `makePdf()`.

Comment: Okay. Cool. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

I think the cleanest solution is to use `hidden` on a parent `div`, and use jsPDF to print the `div` inside.

```
<div hidden>
    <div id="divToPdf">Some content here</div>
</div>
```